# UITabbarController deallocating my viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, ios

I having some problem: Im using `UITabBarController` and 3 tabs, witch one is camera. When i open camera, sometimes give Received Memory warning. And when it happens, all my views are deallocated except the camera. Is it normal? is there some way to control to not happen it? Gratz.

EDIT: im testing with a 3gs model

Comment: are you declaring your viewControllers as properties? or Strong references?

Comment: no, im just adding something like that : TestViewcontroller *t1 = [TesteViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewcontroller" nil]; TestViewcontroller *t3 = [TesteViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewcontroller" nil]; TestViewcontroller *t2 = [TesteViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewcontroller" nil]; tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:t1,t2,t3, nil];
    tabController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean your view controllers' views are deallocated, rather than the view controllers themselves.

This is normal behavior.  UIViewController is built on the assumption that under low-memory conditions, the view can be thrown away if the view controller's view is not on-screen.  You can save your state in `-viewWillUnload` so that you can rebuild it when the view controller's view comes back on screen and is recreated.

This automatic-unloading behavior is removed in iOS 6.

Comment: is it common happen it? for me unload all view give an effect of crash =/ how should i handle it to not unload?

Comment: You can't prevent it from unloading.  What's the actual cause of the crash?

Comment: no, its not a crash, but for me unload the view controllers give this "effect". do you think is because 3gs? or with the code?

Comment: @JuanMunhoesJunior, you need to figure out why you're getting a memory warning, and try to fix that.

Comment: @rdelmar how should i do that? with instruments? or i can just see in code? do you think is it a memory leak? its strange cuz I'm using arc and the app don't crash never, but this memory warning still give me angry and give a bad aspect in app =/

Comment: @JuanMunhoesJunior, I have no idea what's causing it, since you haven't posted any code. It's either a leak, or you're just using too much memory. And, yes, instruments would be a good way to look at it.

Comment: @rdelmar ok, thank you, i ll check out to understand. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, cuz I'm using ARC mode and i think I'm  using wrong.

Comment: You can't ever guarantee that your off-screen view controllers won't have their views thrown away, so it's much smarter to actually work on figuring out how to restore them properly when they do get unloaded.